# Pointer vs Array in function definition: what is the difference between void fct1(int *p) and void fct1(int p[])?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

i wanna know what is the difference between

```
void fct1(int *p)
```

and

```
void fct1(int p[])
```

i know that both are pointers but are there any differences

Comment: @Mark Ransom thank u for the quick reply . but i heard that int p[] is a constant pointer so the address that it points to cannot be changed is that true ?

Comment: ("function pointers" are pointers to functions, not functions that take pointers .. that being said, I'm sure this *must* be a duplicate.)

Comment: @user2142328 `p[]` declares an array of a size to be later determined. That would be illegal in a function parameter, whose size must be known immediately. So in this context it's treated specially, getting an instant transformation to `*p`.

Comment: Note that arrays *are not* pointers, they just act like (constant) pointers sometimes… search for other related answers on this site. In this case, you are declaring a pointer, not an array. Using the array syntax like this may be considered poor form.

Comment: @Potatoswatter when I first learned C the array syntax was more familiar to me so I used it a lot. As I got more familiar with the language I transitioned to the pointer syntax as it better reflected what was really happening.

Comment: @user2142328 I don't know what the standard says about it but gcc allows you to change it just fine: http://ideone.com/et4QEb

Comment: @user2142328 Following my first comment, note that fixing the size as in `p[5]` wouldn't make any difference — the `5` is ignored and it gets the same switcharoo to `*p`. There's no good reason, C just doesn't support it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference when used as a function parameter like that. The compiler treats both forms identically.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. For completeness, here's what the standard says:

C99 standard 6.7.5.3 section 7

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to
>   ‘‘qualified pointer to *type*’’, ...