# What is the difference between char str[] and char *str as function parameters?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, parameters

Say we have the following function prototypes:

```
void function1(char str[]);
void function2(char *str);
```

Now say we have a string `char name[] = "John";` that we wish to pass through these functions. What is the difference between the two? What are their uses and limitations? Are there circumstances in which one is preferred over the other? Would it make a difference if instead the string were initialized as `char *name = "John"`?

I understand the difference between using `char str[]` and `char *str` within a function, but I don't know their behavior as function parameters or arguments.

Comment: If you bothered to look around, you'd surely find the answer.  This has been asked and answered many times over.

Comment: If you copy/paste your entire title into the Google search box, (as I just did, for a laugh), you will get loads of hits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer vs Array in function definition: what is the difference between void fct1(int \*p) and void fct1(int p\[\])?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261509/pointer-vs-array-in-function-definition-what-is-the-difference-between-void-fct)

Comment: You've your answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144535/difference-between-passing-array-fixed-sized-array-and-base-address-of-array-as/16144620#16144620

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **absolutely no difference** in C between

```
void function1(char str[]);
void function2(char *str);
```

because `char str[]` simply reduces to `char *` when passed as argument to a function.And for the record, even `char str[20]` is **exactly** the same thing as the function sees it as `char *str`.

As for whether it would make a difference if the string were initialized as

```
char *name = "John";
```

yes,it does!Here address of that string `John` is being assigned to pointer `name`, and another addresses can be reaassigned to `name` later.

```
char *name="John";
name="Mary";  //Works in C
```

But in

```
char name[]="John";
```

you are initializing a character  array object `name`  to `John`.The difference here is that you just can't reassign another string to `name` after initialization.The following is wrong in C:

```
char name[]="John";
name="Mary";// Wrong
```

While posting questions,search the forum for a minute to see if the question has already been answered.The first part of your question has been asked and  answered very well multiple times.Since you seemed genuinely confused about the second part,I've answered that here.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. **Inside a parameter list**, parameters of the form `T[]` and `T[n]` are silently re-written as `T*` by the compiler. This means that you cannot pass arrays by value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference from a technical point of view. However, if you use [] then you are documenting for the person reading your code that you expect an array.

Comment: The idea of using `[]` to document intent is a good one. I don't see it used much in practice though.