# Use pointer or array in function parameters

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, function-parameter

is `1) float scalar_product(float *x, float *y)` the same as `2) float scalar_product(float x[], float y[])`?

I got some `float a[3], b[3];` which contains some vectors and the function should give me the scalar product.

With my java background I wrote the `2)` function (on paper) but the sample solution used the `1)` with pointer's.

So my questions:
Are they the same? If not, whats the difference and when should I use which?

Comment: When to use what is pretty much a matter of readability. If you want to distinguish between what kind of data is being passed, then by all means use the second method signature. But for all intents and purposes, they're the same.

Comment: This must be a duplicate.

Comment: Here we are: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16258075/694576

Comment: it becomes more tricky when there are two or more dimensions to the array.

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16144535/694576 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15261509/694576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both the versions are *effectively* same, because, when arrays are passed as function arguments, they essentially decay to the pointer to the first element.

So, making the function parameter as pointer or array will have no behavioral change.

Related, `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.3, *Function declarators*

> A declaration of a parameter as *‘‘array of type’’* shall be adjusted to *‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’* [...]

So, `float scalar_product(float x[], float y[])` ends up being the same as `float scalar_product(float *x, float *y)`.